# how to treat dot as a dot and not as a dot operator in php

Tags: php, operators, dot-operator

is there any way to do this in php.i know php treat . as a concatenation operator but i want to force php to treat as a dot when placed between strings

like this

```
      <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $ip = gethostbyname(www.($_GET['ip']).com);
<input type="text" id="ip" name="ip"  >
```

it displays a result

wwwexamplecom

instead i want it like this

www.example.com

i am still a beginner so soory if my question sound too noobish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
     $ip = gethostbyname('www.'.($_GET['ip']).'.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?php
 $ip = gethostbyname('www'.'.'.($_GET['ip']).'.'com');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation:

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.'.($_GET['ip']).'.com');
```